# How do I get a list of all configured WebApi routes in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass configuration values to bootstrap a single page AngularJs app hosted within an MVC app that utilises WebApi (see below from the Razor view, this is achieved by inheriting a BasePage and dependency injecting a Serializer/FinancialYears service).

```
<script>
var angularInitConfig = @Html.Raw(Serializier.Serialize(new {
                   financialYears = FinancialYearsService.GetFinancialYears()
               }));
</script>
```

This works perfectly, however I would really like to be able to extend it to include the routes from my WebApi app to avoid having to configure the endpoints in both the WebApi app AND the AngularJs app individually.

Having poked around in the `RouteTable.Routes` class I can see that the information I require is available and accessible from within the view, however I've been unable to extract it.

So what I'd ideally like to do is generate a collection of objects as defined below from the `RouteTable.Routes` class, serialize them and spit them out in the bootstrap config for the AngularJS app to consume.

```
new {
    name = "SomeService",
    route = "api/{financialYearId}/someservice",
    method = "POST"
}
```

Does anybody have an idea how to extract this information from `RoutesTable.Routes`? Is there an easier way to generate the data required?

NB. All WebApi routes are configured explicitly using the `Routes` attribute as such:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{financialYearId}/someservice")]
```

Comment: Write a serializer, or use a generalized one like Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Did you even read the question? The serialization works fine, I want to extract the data I need from the RouteTable.Routes and pass it to my working serializer to be passed back out to Angular.

Comment: Yes, I read the question.  You need to write some code.  Are you asking how to write that code?

Answer (score 0):

If you create default template asp.net Mvc or WebAPi using Visual Studio, you will get Help in Folder > Areas\HelpPage...and if you access your application in : `Http://yourportapplication/api/Help` if project webapi...
then, you can see the code how to get information...just for started what you looking for,....